# Can you achieve plasma charge?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

This question might be too common, but I'm very curious to understand and find out if this is possible.

We see a lot of sci-fi movies and TV series where they have plasma guns, in reality is this something achievable ?

I'm very familiar with the concept of "anything is possible", but I have no idea about chemistry. All I know is what I read on wikipedia about Plasma or "Phase of Matter".

Can someone give me some clear explanations on what's possible and what not ?

- Can you achieve plasma charge ?
- How dangerous is it ?
- Has someone already achieved this but perhaps keeps it secret ?

Please don't criticise me, it's just a question :)

Comment: What is plasma charge?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Did you really just ask me this ?

Comment: By "plasma charge", do you mean to transfer electric charge with a plasma??

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes.. like a "plasma gun", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_weapon

Comment: If you felt the need to write "Please don't criticise me, it's just a question" then you should make so much effort that you wouldn't  feel it instead of writing this comment. BTW you're making your question as unclear as possible - "achieve" plasma "charge"? Instead of "make a plasma rifle"? Not to say this has little to do with chemistry and a lot with physics and even more with engineering.

Comment: I did not "feel the need" of writing that, I simply added it because people around stack websites understand have a tendency of down voting and criticising instead of actually helping or trying to answer the question. And my question is pretty clear, no I do not and did not and will not ask "how to make a plasma rifle". That is unethical, impractical and not to mention illegal. I asked about exactly what the gentlemen below answered me. So stop wasting your time and my time, if you don't plan on answering the question, thanks.

Comment: No, your question is not clear. Science requires being specific, and goes to great lengths including technical 'jargon' to be precise. 'Plasma charge' is not a technical term that is recognized in physics or chemistry.

Answer (score 3):

A plasma discharge certainly can transfer charge.

Plasma guns are commonly used to reduce static charge, e.g. when pulling plastic wrap from a roll or [for cleaning dust from vinyl discs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CGozrUp-RM). Small ones are available from [about US$100](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAyM8Iet1O8) and [larger plasma guns for more](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/552/1/012017/pdf).

Or you could make your own plasma gun, using a [piezoelectric generator from a US$1 lighter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAyM8Iet1O8). Rather than let a spark jump across the circuit, connect a terminal of the generator to a needle. Squeezing the crystal creates a plasma or ion wind, and in a dark room, you'd see a faint purple glow from the needle tip.

If by "plasma charge", you mean some fictional weapon, it would be *possible* but of limited use. In air, a plasma does not propagate very far, unless there is a powerful ionizing force, e.g. lightning or high-powered radio transmitter, ionizing the path. If you wanted a weapon, then the high-power radio would be more effective than plasma. There is an exception: [an electron beam at a few megavolts in low-pressure air self-focuses](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/552/1/012017/pdf) because of ionization along its path and can propagate a few meters. Of course, in "space", i.e. at *very* low pressure, the plasma would disperse in a puff of gas and ions.

Next time you visit a doctor or dentist, you [might see a plasma gun in action!](https://www.relyon-plasma.com/applications/plasma-sterilization/?lang=en)

Comment: Amazing answer and information! Thank you. And as you can imagine I was relating to the fictional weapon, however I had no idea that "plasmas do not propagate very far". Thanks for all the links, I`m checking them all now :)